# Python 3.3.4 function not computing past a certain argument

Tags: python

I'm solving Euler problem set #2, and I have found the function relevant to what I want I want to do, well partially at least since I'll need to make modifications for even numbers in the fibonacci sequence. I'm trying to print out fibonacci numbers, up to a certain point, n.

```
def fib(n):
if n == 1:
    return 1
elif n == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Giving

```
>>> fib(13)
233
```

However

```
>>> fib(200)
```

returns nothing. I'm not sure if it is taking long to compute, or whatnot. I might try this in C++, but would like some knowledge from here first.

Comment: Too much recursion. The task is really intense. It will take a long time if not reach maximum recursion depth

Comment: a recursive fibonacci implementation has a very bad runtime. have a look at the [python tutorial's fibonacci example](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), that's how you should do it.

Comment: If you need to go over all the fibonacci numbers in Python, you should probably iterate instead of recurse: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9797101

Comment: A recursive fibonnaci function can be salvaged for large values easily using a memoize decorator.  This effectively prevents the explosion in recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just taking a long time to compute, because you're recursively calling `fib()` many, many times. If you add a line as follows you can get status update on it as it runs. It'll take a very long time because of the amount of recursion (if it even finishes).

```
def fib(n):
    print("Fibonacci: {0}".format(n))
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I see the error in this. For reference, here is the relevant documentation that helped me solve my problem thanks to @mata http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions